# Rounding up different numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, rounding

I'm in need of a formula that rounds numbers differently depending on if the number is tens, hundreds, thousands, hundred-thousands, millions, etc. I know the basic rounding functions in Excel but not sure how to do this exactly.

Examples:

```
1 - 999 need to be rounded up to the nearest 10.
1.000 - 99.999 need to be rounded up to the nearest 100.
100.000 - 999.999 need to be rounded up to the nearest 1.000.
1.000.000 - 999.999.999 need to be rounded up to the nearest 100.000.
1.000.000.000 - 999.999.999.999 need to be rounded up to the nearest 1.000.000
```

And all this in single formula that can easily be copied down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do it would be a custom VBA function switching between values - That would give you the most amount of control, but you could do it with nested `IF()` statements too:

```
=IF(A1<1000,CEILING(A1,10),IF(A1<100000,CEILING(A1,100),IF(A1<1000000,CEILING(A1,1000),IF(A1<1000000000,CEILING(A1,100000),CEILING(A1,1000000)))))
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Works like a charm (with the locale edits Jerry proposed)! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ROUNDUP` function with a `LOOKUP` function nested to give you the logic you need, i.e. with values in A2 down use this formula in B2 copied down

`=ROUNDUP(A2,LOOKUP(A2,10^{0,3,5,6,9},-{1,2,3,5,6}))`

This part

`10^{0,3,5,6,9}`

defines the lower bound of each range. And this part:

`-{1,2,3,5,6}`

gives the number of digits to round to, e.g. -2 gives next 100, -3 next 1000 etc.

This rounds **up** to the nearest multiple of 100 etc. so 134 will round to 140. If you want to round to the **nearest** multiple then you can use the exact same formula but with `ROUND` in place of `ROUNDUP`

Comment: I like your function - VERY cool!! - What I'm seeing, though, is that it might also round down, no?? For example, suppose the value was `81`, your formula returns `80` (rather than `90`) since it rounds, not down or up, no??

Comment: Yes, thanks John - I changed it to ROUNDUP which looks to be the requirement - you can use either ROUND or ROUNDUP in the same version

Comment: ...of course you could use the same logic but within a CEILING function as per your answer

Comment: Is the formula you posted supposed to work out of the box (with cell numbers changed of course)? I tried it and it said the formula contains an error.

Comment: @TigerXtrm Might be your locale settings? Try using `=ROUNDUP(A2;LOOKUP(A2;10^{0,3,5,6,9};-{1,2,3,5,6}))` instead (type the formula from scratch, when it breaks on two lines in a comment, it often causes an error).

Comment: For Netherlands you need to change all the commas, so like this `=ROUNDUP(A2;LOOKUP(A2;10^{0;3;5;6;9};-{1;2;3;5;6}))`